# Give spacing between boxes and width of the box in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps

I wish to give more spacing between two infoBoxes in R shiny and increase the width of the box. The infoBoxes and box are both different. The width attribute does not quite seem to work. I shall add the script and snapshot for your reference.

```
/* Script for Info Box:

infoBox("New Orders", 10 * 2, icon = icon("credit-card"), width = 3),

infoBox("New Orders", 10 * 2, icon = icon("credit-card"), width = 3),

infoBox("New Orders", 10 * 2, icon = icon("credit-card"), width = 3)

/* Script for Box in R shiny:

box(title = "Throughput time",status = "primary",solidHeader = T,width = 
150,height = 450, plotOutput("tput_log_plott"))

[![Value box][1]][1]
```

[image: Box]

Comment: Your screenshot has only one box, could you post a screenshot of two boxes and how you want to increase the width?

Comment: Hey, I somehow am not able to upload two images. If you see the value boxes in this video.                                                                                           https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TN1MHtMgWxc, I want to give spacing between them and also increase the width of the box as in the snap.

Comment: For width of the `box` the value is given using `Bootstrap grid system` i.e. `1` to `12`.You can use `fluidRow` and an additional `column` between `infoBox` to give spacing between the infoBoxes.

Comment: Also, how to change the width of the box.

Comment: with a 100% width enveloped in a grid like @SBista mentioned, you should be able to play with the width.

Comment: Sure, can we update the height of the infobox somehow?

Comment: You could use something like `tags$style(type="text/css", ".info-box{min-height:500px;}")`

Comment: Thank yo much SBista and amrrs, Kudos to your help.

Comment: @SBista, I require your help in this post, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47037576/counting-the-number-of-bars-in-a-grouped-bar-chart-in-r-and-plotly/47037897#47037897 
If I click on any bar in the grouped bar chart say "red" or "green", I should get the total bars displayed in the infobox above belonging to that grouped bar chart