# Counting the number of bars in a grouped bar chart in R and plotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly

When I run this script below, It gives me two grouped bar charts. I simply want a vector with the count of number of bars in each group. Attaching the snapshot for reference, clearly, the vector will have two count values. Please help.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
ui <- dashboardPage(
dashboardHeader(title = "Sankey Chart"),
dashboardSidebar(
width = 0
),
dashboardBody(
fluidRow(
column(10,
     uiOutput('box1'),
     tags$br()),
tags$br(),
column(10,


     box(title = "Case Analyses",status = "primary",solidHeader = 
T,width = 1050,height = 452,
         plotlyOutput("case_hist"))
))
)
)
server <- function(input, output) 
{ 
output$case_hist <- renderPlotly(
{

iris$iris_limits <- cut(iris$Sepal.Length, c(1,3,6,9))
iris$ID <- factor(1:nrow(iris))
gg <- ggplot(iris, aes(x=ID, y=Sepal.Length, fill=iris_limits)) + 
geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") +
facet_wrap(~iris_limits, scales="free_x", labeller=label_both) +
theme_minimal() + xlab("") + ylab("Sepal Length") +
theme(axis.text.x=element_blank())
ggplotly(gg)
}
)
output$box1 <- renderUI({
tagList(
infoBox("Total Cases", "a" , icon = icon("fa fa-briefcase"))
)
})
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: Similar requirement using R shiny]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're effectively trying to do here is extract data from the plot element. In this case, we can do this by extracting the plot data and storing it in a temporary data frame, then making a table of the `PANEL` variable to see how many elements are in each panel.

```
gg<- ggplot(df, aes(alpha, bravo))  # however you made your plot
temp <- data.frame(ggplot_build(gg)$data[[1]]) 
table(temp$PANEL)
```

edit: the plot I was playing with to create this answer had the data applied as the third element, thus I originally had a 3 instead of 1 in line two of the code. Replace that number with whichever layer has your data.  If you do a simple plot that only has one element (like yours with `geom_bar()` first above) then your first element should be the data and the code above should work.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have edited this post, please help me with the similar requirement in R shiny.

Comment: If I click on any bar in the grouped bar chart say "red" or "green", I should get the total bars displayed in the infobox above belonging to that grouped bar chart

Comment: @AshminKaul it's standard procedure around here to not edit a post to ask for additional support, but instead create a new one. I'm not as familiar with shiny anyways so I can't help you there.

Comment: @AshminKaul, instead of editing a question for which you already have an accepted answer, you should post a new question.